# Template not working in IE because of special character

Tags: internet-explorer, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new with Vue.js. I receive invalid character error in IE for templates like this:

```
  template: `
    <div contenteditable="true" @blur="emitChange">
      {{ content }}
    </div>
  `,
```

See my application here: https://jsfiddle.net/ns6umqv2/ (working with Google Chrome).

I understand IE doesn't like this character: `

but I have no idea how to rewrite my code.

Comment: You could use another way of structuring the application by using seperate files for each component. This allows each component to have a "real" `template` section: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be awesome. I will try.

Comment: @BennettDams Yes, this was the solution. Thank you!